# Error when deploy Rails app to render.com: "Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-22"] but your local platform is x86_64-linux"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, render.com

When I tried to deploy to render.com, error occurred, I looked at the error, the following message appeared

```
==> Running build command 'bundle install; bundle exec rake assets:precompile; bundle exec rake assets:clean;'...
Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-22"] but your local platform is x86_64-linux.
Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
```

investigation
First x86_64-darwin-22 of all, what is it? So I looked it up and found out:

- x86_64: Number of bits (amount of information) of the PC's CPU
- darwin: OS developed by Apple. Pronounced Darwin, it seems to be the basis of Mac OS
- 22: Is it the version number?

I want to replace my Mac with an Apple silicon one soon...

but your local platform is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile  Therefore, it seems that you need to add the platform of your environment to Gemfile.lock.

Solution
Use the command in the local environment bundle lockto update Gemfile.lock
Run the following command

```
$ bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

Execution result

```
x86_64-linux added!
```

`Gemfile.lock`:

```
+ nokogiri (1.13.9-x86_64-linux)
+   racc (~> 1.4)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-22
+ x86_64-linux
```

Comment: Did you commit changes and try again?

Answer (score 1):

There is similar [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1106). It's about Heroku, not about render.com, but also should work

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux --add-platform ruby
bundle install
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Bundler fix"
```

And after that repeat deploy (push new commit to your branch)